# Hierarchy Slicers Not Working in Power BI due to outdated SQL Analysis Services Version Error

Tags: powerbi, ssas, hierarchy, slicers

I receive the following error when trying to insert hierarchy data type into slicer visuals (whether it is date hierarchy or some other data group, such as customer info hierarchy):

[image]

Basically, it claims that I use an outdated (older than 2019) model of SQL analysis services which is untrue. I (my workplace) use(s) the latest version of SQL Analysis Services (SQL Analysis Services 2019 CU20 version 15.0.4312.2). My powerbi desktop version is also the latest one, from May 2023 (2.117.984.0 64-bit (May 2023)).

Any known solutions or workarounds?